# Does anyone have idea to remove default push up of main content in Sothree SlideUpPanel layout?

Tags: android, android-layout, github

I have done an layout using sothree slideuppanel from github [link here](https://github.com/arbuzz/AndroidSlidingUpPanel-ScrollView).
When i using it the main content also scroll up on dragview. There they said that there is an method `setOverlayed`. But i tried that one not working for me. Does anyone have idea about this?

This is my code

```
<com.sothree.slidinguppanel.SlidingUpPanelLayout
    xmlns:sothree="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/sliding_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:gravity="bottom"
    sothree:umanoPanelHeight="68dp"
    sothree:umanoShadowHeight="4dp"
    sothree:umanoParalaxOffset="100dp"
    sothree:umanoDragView="@+id/dragView"
    sothree:umanoOverlay="true">
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">


    <include
        android:id="@+id/tool_bar"
        layout="@layout/tool_bar">
    </include>

    <SlidingTabLayout
        android:id="@+id/tabs"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@color/black"
        android:elevation="2dp"/>

    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/pager"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1">

    </android.support.v4.view.ViewPager>

</LinearLayout>
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="#ffffff"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:focusable="false"
        android:id="@+id/dragView">


        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_gravity="start"
            android:gravity="start"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:id="@+id/actionBarCustom"
            android:background="@color/black"
            android:layout_height="?actionBarSize">
            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/backFloatMenu"
                android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:src="@drawable/abc_ic_ab_back_mtrl_am_alpha"
                android:layout_height="match_parent" />
        </LinearLayout>


        <include
            android:id="@+id/sv"
            layout="@layout/float_latout"/>


    </LinearLayout>

</com.sothree.slidinguppanel.SlidingUpPanelLayout>
```

Comment: This link may help you https://github.com/ShakeJ/AndroidSlidingUpPanel/blob/cf95b2af29c785e57e19871ba4ea9ad19a51fcf7/library/src/com/sothree/slidinguppanel/SlidingUpPanelLayout.java

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This line :

```
    sothree:umanoOverlay="true"
```

Define that the panel overlay the main content.

Comment: when i use it actionBar also push up. i don't want that push up. MainContent must stay in it's position :(

Comment: You say that the ActionBar also pushed? even after you set umanoOverlay="true"?

Comment: Where you put this ActionBar? Maybe edit your question with the xml of your layout

Comment: Looks OK , maybe the problem is in the toolBar, maybe he have some listener that cause to this behaviour